# Extensions adding U2F/Yubikey support to Opera

Tags: security

[Universal 2nd Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) is a new authentication protocol. It is supported by Chrome, by Firefox via plugin, but I use Opera.

I can't find any of these myself on the Opera Extensions gallery, and the browser doesn't support U2F hardware natively yet; are there any projects out there which bring this functionality to Opera?